# How can I omit temporary variable at loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I need to run a code block at 100 times, I'll write code like this:

```
for x in xrange(100):
    #code block
```

But usually I won't use temporary variable `x` again.

And I think use this kind of temporary variable will cause code ugly.

Is there anyway can help me omit this kind of temporary variable?

Thank you.

Comment: Not if you are using a `for` loop. The convention is to use name the variable  `_` or `__`; the latter won't clash with the name `_` being used for the `gettext()` function.

Comment: you can use `_` or prepend `dummy` to the variable you declare